# How to disable infrared focus assist beam on my YN568ex

Tags: flash, canon-7d

I recently got a YN568ex speedlight and every time I focus, the infrared focus assist beam lights up. This is great for low light situations but I want to be able to turn it off when there's enough light for focusing. BTW I'm using a Canon 7D.

P.S: I already read the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!!!!
The AF-assist beam firing setting is located in the External flash C.Fn setting under the flash control menu.